# Removing all domains from Network Manager DNS Search List

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, networkmanager

I'm trying to remove all values from the domain search list that's generated by the network manager.  However I cannot get it to provide a blank list.  I have tried using "ignore-auto-dns but the domain is still present.  Are there any other commands that I can issue to remove all domains from the list?

I have also tried the following:
`nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search ""` and
`nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "."`, but neither would remove `search c.project.internal` from `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns no
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli con down "System eth0" && nmcli con up "System eth0"
Connection 'System eth0' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1)
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli device show eth0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         42:01:0A:F8:06:9A
GENERAL.MTU:                            1460
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     System eth0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.248.6.154/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.248.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.248.0.1/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.248.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 10.248.6.154/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.248.253.253
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.248.254.254
IP4.DNS[3]:                             169.254.169.254
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          c.project.internal
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4001:aff:fef8:69a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search c.project.internal google.internal
nameserver 10.248.253.253
nameserver 10.248.254.254
nameserver 169.254.169.254
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli con down "System eth0" && nmcli con up "System eth0"
Connection 'System eth0' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3)
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ nmcli device show eth0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         42:01:0A:F8:06:9A
GENERAL.MTU:                            1460
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     System eth0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.248.6.154/32
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.248.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.248.0.1/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.248.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 10.248.6.154/32, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.248.253.253
IP4.DNS[2]:                             10.248.254.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4001:aff:fef8:69a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
[root@instance-1.c:/home] $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search c.project.internal
nameserver 10.248.253.253
nameserver 10.248.254.254
```

The above example shows that ignore-auto-dns is in fact ignoring the domain passd from DHCP, but the network manager is still getting a domain from somewhere.

Comment: Is your goal to remove any traces of `c.project.internal` domain from `/etc/resolv.conf` ? You need some script to do this ? I'm not sure what the question is here...

Comment: what gives `NetworkManager --print-config`? Does it indicate that DNS settings are set globally? Then see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/484#note_556816 for how to unset it.

Comment: Does @Serhii Rohozai explanation clarify your question? If yes, can you please accept and upvote the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to "remove all values from the domain search list" from `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Have a look at the documentation [Advanced VPC concepts](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/advanced-vpc):

> **DNS server**
>
> Each instance's metadata server acts as a DNS server. It stores the
> DNS entries for all VPC network IP addresses in the local VPC network
> and calls Google's public DNS server for entries outside the VPC
> network. You cannot configure this DNS server. The DHCP client on each
> instance is configured to manage the instance's /etc/resolv.conf file.
>
> **You can add your own search domain or nameservers to the instance's
> `/etc/resolv.conf` by modifying the DHCP policy.** Many Linux
> distributions allow these modifications to persist via
> `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. See the [Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns) documentation for more
> information.

Also, have a look at the documentation [Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns) section [Internal DNS and resolv.conf](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf):

> **By default, most Linux distributions store DHCP information in resolv.conf. Compute Engine instances are configured to renew DHCP
> leases every 24 hours**. For instances that are enabled for zonal DNS,
> the DHCP lease expires every hour. **DHCP renewal overwrites this
> file, undoing any changes that you might have made**. Instances using
> zonal DNS have both zonal and global entries in the resolv.conf file.

and at the section [Accessing VMs by internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#access_by_internal_DNS):

> **Important**: Compute Engine instances receive internal DNS resolution information as part of their DHCP leases. By default,
> resolution of internal DNS names is handled by the instance's metadata
> server (169.254.169.254). **If you change the name server
> configuration for your instance, you might not be able to use internal
> DNS names.** Any replacement name server software must support the
> Local Subnet Routes feature of [RFC 3442](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442).

In addition, have a look at the documentation [VPC firewall rules overview](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) section [VPC Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#alwaysallowed):

> **Google runs a local metadata server alongside each instance at
> 169.254.169.254. This server is essential** to the operation of the instance, so the instance can access it regardless of any firewall
> rules you configure.

So, if you really want to change values in `resolv.conf` it's safer to modify the DHCP policy.

Answer (score 0):

From `man nm-settings` under the `dns-search` section:

> Domains starting with a tilde ('~') are considered 'routing' domains and are used only to decide the interface over which a query must be forwarded; they are not used to complete unqualified host names.

So from what I can tell, you need a few commands:

```bash
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns-search "~c.project.internal"
nmcli con mod "System eth0" +ipv4.dns-search "~google.internal"

# probably also want the ipv6 version too:
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv6.dns-search "~c.project.internal"
nmcli con mod "System eth0" +ipv6.dns-search "~google.internal"
```

If I understand the man page correctly, this will cause all your regular `c.project.internal` and `google.internal` ***queries*** to still go over the `System eth0` connection, but DNS ***searches*** (for determining FQDNs of hostnames) will no longer be performed.

*Disclaimer: I just learned this myself -- I could be wrong about some details.*